# Primary partition disk shows unformatted

Tags: hard-drive

I have a problem with my hard disk, a few days ago my PC crashed and an error message appeared on the screen stating unable to read A disk, please press crtl atl del. After doing that it kept looping.

I need to recover my data on the disk therefore, I tried to slave the disk to another computer.

When I done that my primary partition disk shows as unformatted and im unable to read data off there.

Can someone please help and suggest me what I can do in order to read the disk and I can recover my data.

I am using windows XP 32bit (NTFS)

Any help or suggestions will be helpful

Thank you

Comment: you should edit your question and add your comment there

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily recover your lost files from crashed hard drive on Windows XP 32bit (NTFS).  As per of my experience I suggest you utility referred as Remo Recover. I recovered my lost data from crashed hard drive by using this tool. Just try it.

Comment: This is not so much an answer as a suggestion. It might be better as a comment for the user to try first. Then, if it's found to work, you would be in a good position to post as an answer.